# Json data fetching lag problem from jsonbin.io

Tags: java, android, json

I'm working on a app that is a simple game, so here's a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSIFw.png) for the UI I have, the problem is when I fetch a level using Json web service, the first time I choose the level from [`activity_level_list`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyOXd.png), the picture and level number doesn't show, only the 4 words works but neither the image nor the level number appear like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH9BL.png).

> NOTE: The image URL variable is null (because of the lag that happens the first time I open first level activity) so an error happen (that's why it shows ic_launcher instead of showing the level picture).

So, I said the problem was "lag" because when I go back to `LevelList` and click on level 1, the picture and the level number get fetched and everything becomes good.

How can I make it both the image and level ID appears in the first time I open the activity?

> NOTE: I use jsonbin.io for data fetching.

Here's my Json data fetching class:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    String update = "4";

    String data ="";

    String id;
    String img;
    String w1;
    String w2;
    String w3;
    String w4;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e42776dd18e4016617690ce/" + update);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while(line != null){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }

            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);

//            for(int i = 0 ;i < JA.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(1);

                        id = (String) JO.get("id");
                        img = (String) JO.get("img");
                        w1 = (String) JO.get("w1");
                        w2 = (String) JO.get("w2");
                        w3 = (String) JO.get("w3");
                        w4 = (String) JO.get("w4");

//            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        int levelId = Integer.parseInt(id);
        levelId++;

        LevelActivity.levelID = String.valueOf(levelId);
        LevelActivity.imageURL = img;
        LevelActivity.button1Word = w1;
        LevelActivity.button2Word = w2;
        LevelActivity.button3Word = w3;
        LevelActivity.button4Word = w4;

    }


}
```

Thanks ^-^

Comment: You are just updating the values for the variables of image and levelID in onPostExecute() method. You have to set thses variables to your views in your activity after the data is fetched i.e. in onPostExecute() method

Comment: I already did it in LevelActivity in onCreate() method

Comment: You did it when the activity is created. You have to set the the variables again when the new data is fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just needed to update the image and level text view number in `onPostExecute` method to make it load from the first time.
>   **Answer by NIKHIL AGGARWAL**